# Woocommerce round the tax rate

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a specific fixed tax to a product. So i found a solution which it worked for me. 
Problem is that I want a 4.7% tax, but its round up to 5%.
The tax in woocommerce is using a 4 decimal rate: Rate %: 4.7000.

Any fixes for this one?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you can use round() with second parameter of "The optional number of decimal digits to round to. " Checkout  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: I don't want to round it. This is done by default. I want to get the exact value

Comment: looking into it since this is done by woocommerce pugins and not my code

Answer (score 0):

If anyone return to this question:
under your activated theme: review-order.php, is printing the tax rounding up.
echo sprintf('%.0f%%', $tax_rate['rate']).
You can change the value to 1 or 2 to get the decimal number.
So for me it was: echo sprintf('%.1f%%', $tax_rate['rate']).